# finding the mac address of an network interface from kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am making a module in which I require the mac address of network interface . Is there any function through which I can find the mac address without doing ioctl in user space.

Comment: arp_find() seems to work if the entry is already learnt but apparently it is depricated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify which kernel version you're using. This is based on the latest 3.something version, but it should be very similar for older versions:

Assuming you have the struct net_device (and if you don't, you're probably doing something wrong), you can just look at the dev_addrs field. It contains a list of all of the devices hardware addresses.

The is_etherdev_addr function in include/linux/etherdevice.h is probably a good example on how to read it.

Comment: Hi how should I access the mac address from dev_addrs feild .... by the way I am using 2.6.34...

Comment: You can use `dev_addr`, which is a simple `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all `netdev` available on system and get their names and MACs:

```
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
```

...

```
struct net_device *dev;

for_each_netdev(&init_net, dev) {
    pr_info("Interface %s with MAC %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n"
            , dev->name
            , dev->dev_addr[0]
            , dev->dev_addr[1]
            , dev->dev_addr[2]
            , dev->dev_addr[3]
            , dev->dev_addr[4]
            , dev->dev_addr[5]
        );
}
```

See [hwaddr-rand](https://github.com/defiant-labs/hwaddr-rand/blob/master/hwaddr_rand.c) source code for complete example.

Answer (score -2):

please refer to the code below:

```
    struct ifreq tmp;
    struct socket * sock = NULL;
    struct net_device *dev = NULL;
    struct net *net;
    int retval;
    char mac_address[6];

    retval = sock_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, &sock);
    net = sock_net(sock->sk);

    dev = dev_get_by_name_rcu(net,"eth0");

    memcpy(&mac_address,dev->dev_addr,6);

    sock_release(sock);
```